# Triggering an onchange event within an onload function

Tags: javascript, onchange, onload

I have a webpage with two drop down menus. The first one (`id = ddlIndustry`) has a 'Go' button that refreshes the page after selecting an option from the drop down. Once this is done, a selection can be made in the second drop down (`id = region`). This has an onchange property that is triggered and refreshes the page when a selection is made.

I am trying to write a set of commands in Javascript that selects an option from the first dropdown, clicks the 'Go' button, and once the page is refreshed, selects an option from the second drop down and programatically triggers the onchange event.

The code I have so far is:

```
document.all.ddlIndustry.selectedIndex = 21;
document.getElementById("cmdChart").click();
window.onload = function(){
    document.all.region.selectedIndex = 2;
    document.all.region.onchange();
};
```

This lets me select a `ddlIindustry` index and press 'Go', but does not select a region and trigger an onchange event. However, when I select an industry and press go manually, the second part of the code:

```
document.all.region.selectedIndex = 2;
document.all.region.onchange();
```

does allow me to select a region and trigger the onchange event.

How can I do both things together?

Edit: I have tried this in both Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.120 m) and IE (Version 11.0.9600.17280)

Comment: [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `document.all` says it's no longer supported. The reason to link to MSDN instead of MDN is, that `document.all` _was_  supported in IE _only_. Also, `onchange` can't be triggered programmatically. What you can do, is to call the event handler function directly.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I can trigger the onchange programattically using - document.all.region.selectedIndex = 2;
document.all.region.onchange(); - This works when I execute it by itself, but I cannot get this to work within the window.onload = function(){}.

Comment: `document.all` seems to work in all modern browsers (also in IE11), obviously I've missed something. Actually `.onchange()` doesn't trigger `onchange` event, it's a direct call to the handler, when `.onchange = function(){..}` has been set. Anyway, your code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/pxjh3zq1/) on `window.onload` too. The only difference is, that I've attached the `onchange` listener within `onload` handler. As a conclusion, I'd say, the `window.onload`, or at least the lines in the post, are never executed. Is there more than one `window.onload = ...` assignment in the code?

Comment: No, that is the complete code. I am running all of it at once from the Chrome or IE console.

Comment: Uhh... That's it, `window.onload` has fired a long time before you're writing the code to the console. It is not executed, as I've said in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look very promising. Well, thanks for your help. I'll have to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you write something like given below will work.

```
region.selectedIndex = 2;
region.onchange();
```

Comment: Again, that works fine by itself, but not within the window.onload = function(){ }. When I have the region.selectedIndex and region.onchange statements with the onload function, the zero index is always selected rather than the index value I choose (which is 2 here).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as well:

```
var body_Onload = function(){
    document.all.region.selectedIndex = 2;
    document.all.region.onchange();
};
```

In HTML add this function to body tag as

```
<body onLoad="body_Onload">
...
...
</body>
```